# Query for extracting rows where a column being null always returns empty even though DB has matching records

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

Always the following code returns empty rows, although there are matching records in DB:

```
String sql = "select * from test5 where id2 = ? ";
    return opsbldJdbcTemplate.query(sql, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
        }
    }, new ResultSetExtractor<List<Map<String,Object>>>() {
        public List<Map<String,Object>> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            List<Map<String,Object>> lms = new ArrayList<>();
            while(rs.next()) {
                Map<String,Object> mss = new HashMap<>();
                lms.add(mss);
                mss.put("id1", "" + rs.getInt(1));
                mss.put("id2", "" + rs.getLong(2));
                mss.put("id4", "" + rs.getDouble(4));
            }

            return lms;
        }
     });
}
```

```
ppql=> \d test5
                      Table "public.test5"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id1    | integer               |           |          |
 id2    | bigint                |           |          |
 id3    | smallint              |           |          |
 id4    | double precision      |           |          |
 id5    | numeric(10,2)         |           |          |
 id6    | real                  |           |          |
 id7    | character varying(30) |           |          |
 id8    | text                  |           |          |
 id9    | character(30)         |           |          |


ppql=> select * from test5 where id2 is NULL;
 id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5 | id6 | id7 | id8 | id9
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
   4 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
(1 row)
```

Not sure why it is not returning any rows.. Have done all sorts of attempts to get at it, but to no avail

I have tried many variants of the query function and queryforList etc.. but doesnt help

Comment: To check for `NULL` you'd have to use `id2 IS NULL` **not** `id2 = NULL`.

Comment: You have used <String, Object> as List. While printing are you converting the value to a printable type ex. String / Int instead of Object? Also, check for null for each value, before printing.

Comment: All that have been tried.. I tried " IS ? " but that throws some other error.. and I printed the List using logger and also using automatic Rest json response.. So any data thats there should get printed.. but it prints only "[]"

Comment: What error did you get with IS?  It should work fine for nulls.  To have it work where id2 is null or is an actual number you could change the where clause to WHERE id2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?

Answer (score 0):

The null check can not be done with `= null` instead it must be done like this:

```
select * from test5 where id2 is null
```

If one tries to do that with setting the null, via

```
ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
```

it gives an exception from the JDBC driver:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 34
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
```

One possible solution is to make a specific query in this case:

```
select * from test5 where id2 is null
```

**Test**

Here a self-contains Java Program with JDBC:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection connection = createConnection();
            try (connection) {
                /*
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "select * from test5 where id2 is ?");
                ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
                 */
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "select * from test5 where id2 is null");

                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        int id1 = rs.getInt(1);
                        System.out.println("found entry with id1='" + id1 + "'");
                    }
                }
                ps.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static Connection createConnection()
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/stephan";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "stephan");
        props.setProperty("password", "secret");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    }
}
```

If the content of the test5 table looks like this:

```
stephan=# select * from test5;
 id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5 | id6 | id7 | id8 | id9 
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
   4 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
(1 row)
```

then the output on the debug console is like this:

```
found entry with id1='4'
```